# Stored procedure in pgsql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedure in PostgreSQL (pgSQL) .I need some one help  to crack my problem .I am doing the migration process from oracle to PostgreSQL for that I have used some stored procedure concept. I have tried in SQL stored procedure  its working in SQL, but same code i have trying to convert into pgSQL. I have faced a issue in line by line .can any one help me to convert same code SQL into PostgreSQL. i have attached my SQL procedure code below. can any one suggest me aright way to process the code.

code:

```
delimiter;
drop procedure if exists patient_form_values;
delimiter $$
create procedure patient_form_values()

begin

declare columnName varchar(200) ;
declare done tinyint default 0;
declare cur1 cursor for select distinct COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'CASESHEETCOMPLAINTS' and table_schema='hms_empty_copy';
declare continue handler for not found set done = 1;
open cur1;
read_loop : loop
fetch from cur1 into columnName;
if done then leave read_loop; 
end if;

set @insertValues := concat('INSERT INTO patient_form_temp(patient_id, form_template_id, creator_id, created_date)
SELECT c.patient_id as patient_id, 41 AS form_template_id, 2 AS creator_id, c.created_date AS created_date 
FROM CASESHEETCOMPLAINTS c 
WHERE c.', columnName,' IS NOT NULL GROUP BY c.patient_id, c.created_date'); 

select @insertValues;

prepare stmt from @insertValues;
execute stmt;
end loop;
close cur1;
end $$ 
delimiter ;
call patient_form_values();
drop procedure if exists patient_form_values;

--To delete the empty records.
DELETE FROM patient_form WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT patient_form_id FROM patient_form_value);


insert into patient_form(patient_id, form_template_id, creator_id, created_date)select patient_id, form_template_id, creator_id, created_date from patient_form_temp GROUP BY patient_id, created_date
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error while creating function in postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585003/syntax-error-while-creating-function-in-postgresql)

Comment: You could start with the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html